# Best way to structure a database for scaling

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a project that has the potential to have a large number of users each of which will be managing their own unique data sets. I am thinking the data can be stored in one of two ways.

1) Create a completely different database for each user so that their data is fully separate from everyone elses

2) Share the data in the same database, and segregate it at the query level using a user_id field.

The schema will always be identical for each user.

The main thing is that the system will need to be able to scale, and I am not sure if having potentially several thousand different databases, or storing millions of records in the same tables would scale better.

I am interested in hearing from anyone who has dealt with this kind of situation in the past and what pitfalls might be out there with either option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 should be your best bet. Databases are usually designed to work with millions and millions of rows and a lots of data. So, as long as you design your schema correctly and have proper indexes, fill factors etc., option 2 will lead you to the scaling that you are looking for. As DarthVader said, learn more about database design.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the scaling aspect that you have already identified, there are a few other concerns which may drive your decision - the 'large number of users' can also mean such a range of numbers that you would be best to clarify.

Other operational concerns:

- Security - relying on a user_id field within your code relies on there being no error or flaw that allows a user to see / maniuplate other user's data.
- Upgrades - goes both ways, but you either upgrade everyone at once (single DB) or by splitting - allow yourself to upgrade diffent sets of users at different times.
- Backup / Restore - depending on the restore requirements and SLAs, you may find that having everyone in a single database creates too much of a problem when it comes to backup / restore. If a single client wants to restore their data, the operational overhead when it is combined with all the other client's data is not trivial. Equally, having lots of databases = lots of seperate backups.
- Scalability - having the ability to place different user's databases on seperate servers can aid scale, instead of requiring a big iron DB server. But again, that is a management overhead.

Multi-tenancy of an application and it's data source is not an easy question / answer - understanding more about how many users is 'large' in this case might be, combined with the operational concerns provide you guidance.

Comment: * I am fairly confident that I can handle the security for either option.

* I can see advantages either way for upgrades, but think I would be upgrading everyone all at once whichever data model is chosen. 

* I see backups as having advantages / disadvantages no mater what data model is used.

I can see the pros and cons to either approach. this is purely a scalability quesiton for me.

Comment: The operational constraints, especially around upgrades / backup / restore can be a mare if not planned. Without all information, It's not really possible to present a 'right' answer - or be 100% definative about a solution with the realms of SO.

Comment: You can scale with either mechanism, some of the largest data is held in a sharded / map reduce style, and equally, multi billion row datasets exist on single database servers (the hardware isnt cheap).

Answer (score 1):

Dont create seperate database for each user. That s not good.

What if you will have million users?

Create table for users and entities that belong to same context. you cant scale applications like that. and before learning about scalability. you need to learn about database design and how databases works.